# Random Images from my Image Hosting website should diplayed in my android app when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, button

I'm developing an app. It has one Imageview and one button. I want that when user click on the button, everytime the Imageview loads some random image from my Image hosting website.

Comment: This is not a question. Have you tried to implement it yourself? Or you just expecting source code?

Comment: @thealeksandr Yes I have implemented. But not getting Idea how to do. I have just Imageview and button inside a layout. I don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ClickListener for your button that when clicked, loads an image to your view. For image loading there are several libs to choose from, you can use glide for example:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

            GlideApp.with(this).load("your_url_here").into(imageView);
        }
    });
```

So whenever you click your button an image gets loaded. Here is github link to library: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

P.S.: When asking questions remember to put as much information as you can so people don't call you on being lazy or something else.